# pst-eucl bold labels and arc sizes

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

I got a couple of questions about pst-eucl. How can I make a point label bold? I've tried the following permutations

```
\pstGeonode[PointName=\textbf{A}](1,1){A}(-1,-1){B}
\pstGeonode[PointName={\bf A}](1,1){A}(-1,-1){B}
\pstGeonode[PointName=\bf{A}](1,1){A}(-1,-1){B}
```

but I can't make it work.

Also, how can I control the radius of the angles arcs? So if i have overlapping arcs they don't intersect.

Comment: Can you add a minimal (non) working example to play with?

Comment: I've updated my solution to be a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've frequently had this problem.  There seems to be something in the way that key `PointName` is implemented in `pst-eucl` that's getting in the way.

The way `\pstGeonode` is setting the node names is through an artifact of how `\psnode` works---which is expecting something expandable in `\edef` to create string for the internal name for the node.  When you're formatting the text with something like `\textbf`, you're creating something that won't work as a node name.

But the good news is  that there is a reasonable work-around:

```
    \pstGeonode[PointName=none](1,-2){C}
    \rput([nodesep=1em,angle=-90]C){\textbf{C}}
```

So, the MWE is now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-4,-4)(4,4)

    \pstGeonode[PointName=none](1,1){A}
    \uput[135](A){\texttt{A}}

    \pstGeonode[PointName=none](1,-1){B}
    \uput[-45](B){{\scriptsize B}}

    \pstGeonode[PointName=none](1,-2){C}
    \uput[-90](C){\textbf{C}}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

There are actually two different syntaxes which work here:

You can use `\rput` and pass key-values:

```
\rput([nodesep=1em,angle=135]A){\textbf{A})
```

But `pstricks` provides a better vehicle for applying labels to nodes:

```
\uput*{labelsep}[refangle]{rotation}(x,y){stuff}
```

where the `labelsep` and `rotation` arguments may be omitted.  In place of the coordinates `(x,y)` you may substitute the node name `(A)`.